# Calling an overloaded function and retrieving data from a function prototype in C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I might not have even asked that question correctly, but whatever. And I'll probably have many more questions in the near future as well. The point here is to use overloaded functions (with a double input and void input not being included in this sample). But I'm unsure why my overloaded function for char input is not being executed. I know I'm missing something, probably pass-by-value, but I've tried to brainstorm over it and gotten close to nowhere.
Btw, this is FAR from finished code. This is just to get the char version of input to execute correctly while staying as an overloaded function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

char input(char letter, string prompt_text = "Enter your letter (a to z): ",
    string error_message_text = "Error! ")
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt_text;
        char letter{};
        cin >> setw(1) >> letter;
        tolower(letter);

        if (not(isalpha(letter)))
        {
            cout << error_message_text;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            return letter;
        }
    }
};


double input(double min_number=-100, double max_number=100, string prompt_text="Enter your number (-100 to 100): ", string error_message_text="Error! ")
{
cout<<prompt_text;
double number{};
cin>>number;
if (isalpha(number))
{
 cout<<error_message_text;
}
return number;
}; 
// for getting a number

void input(double x, double y, string prompt_text="Enter your point: ")
{
cout<<prompt_text;
double point{};
cin>>point;

}; 

int main()
{
    input();
}
```

Comment: You have a least two problems that I can see: First is that you attempt to call the `input` function without arguments, but it requires at least one (the first `letter` argument); The second is that you *shadow* the `letter` argument variable with another variable with the same name.

Comment: Oh, and I don't see any overloading in the code you show.

Comment: I did try inserting 'letter' into the input(); function in int main();, but I just get 'letter is not defined in this scope'. Which makes me think that it is not getting called or passed to correctly.

Comment: Went ahead and added some of the code I left out back in to help get a better picture.

Comment: Now you have overloads. But you need to actually pass the arguments needed for the function you want to call! Perhaps you should take some time with your text-book and review the chapters on functions and how to call them.

Comment: I have been trying to do that (looking it over repeatedly), but it's just not... sinking into my head. I don't know why, I feel like it should be obvious, but nothing's just... clicking.

Comment: `char letter; input(letter);` to call the first overload. For the next two it's a little harder since the three first arguments are really the same, which overload should be called for `input(50.0, 150.0)` for example?